# Capistrano deployment with Amazon EFS (bind mounted folders) failing when using with :linked_dirs

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, capistrano, capistrano3

I am having an issue trying to use Capistrano to deploy an application that requires having several Amazon EFS bind mounts inside of the deployment (current) folder.

I have a directory on the webserver in the root called `/webroot` inside of it is where all of our code currently is along with about 7 folders (bind mounts) that are shared across three nodes.

Inside of my `deploy.rb` I have the following line `set :deploy_to, "/webroot/testingCap"` in which Capistrano is deploying the code into the symlinked folder `current`. This is great but now when it gets to the step of symlinking the bind mount directories for example:`/webroot/uploads` it throws an error:

`rm -rf /webroot/uploads
rm: cannot remove '/webroot/uploads'
Device or resource busy`

I am not sure why it is trying to forcefully remove that directory? I thought it was supposed to just symlink to the directory.

My linked_dirs part looks like this inside of `deploy.rb`:
`append :linked_dirs, "/webroot/uploads"`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`:linked_dirs` only works with **relative paths** and **always uses Capistrano's `shared` directory.**

When you add e.g. `"foo"` to `:linked_dirs`, Capistrano will create a symlink within your deployed app. If anything already exists there, it will delete it first (that is why you are seeing the `rm -rf`).

The destination of that link will always be to the same name in Capistrano's `shared` directory. So the chain of events will be like this:

```
rm -rf /webroot/testingCap/current/foo
ln -s /webroot/testingCap/shared/foo /webroot/testingCap/current/foo
```

Thus if you look inside `current`, you will a link that points

```
foo -> /webroot/testingCap/shared/foo
```

Notice that the path relative to `current` is *identical* to the path relative to `shared`. This is how `:linked_dirs` works and you can't change it.

For example, if your app expects to store uploads in `public/uploads`, you will need the exact same relative path to exist inside `shared` in order for the link to be established. In other words, the link will point like this:

```
/webroot/testingCap/current/public/uploads -> /webroot/testingCap/shared/public/uploads
```

In your case, I suspect you *can* get this to work, but you'll need to make sure that your mount points are located exactly where Capistrano expects them to be.